# How do I get my Mac to do nothing when I insert a cd?

Tags: macbook-pro, itunes, optical-drive

I recently got an older MacBook Pro that has an optical drive. Every time I insert a CD, iTunes will always respond in some way.

I have already tried changing the setting in **iTunes > Preferences > General**, but I don't see the option I want.

How do I get this Mac to absolutely do nothing when I insert a CD?

Comment: Disconnect its cable... ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this in your Mac's system preferences:

1. Go to **Apple > System Preferences > CDs & DVDs**
2. You'll see a menu for *When you insert a music CD*
3. Change that menu from "Open iTunes" to "Ignore".

**Notes:**

- You may also want to check the options for Blank CD and Blank DVD as they also include built-in options to open iTunes.
- The other menus also provide the ability to run a script, so if you got the MacBook from someone and you're using their old account, these may be worth checking as well in case they're launching iTunes or another application.

Comment: Anybody got an updated answer for the Music app on Catalina? I've got my system preferences set as shown in this answer and still get Music launched every time I insert a CD.